# Why does calling a method after a ScheduledExecutorService event only sometimes work?

Tags: java, methods, scheduledexecutorservice

Given the following code, where `timer` is a `ScheduledExecutorService` object and `runThis` is a `Runnable` object that changes the appearance of a JButton.

```
Sound.play();
timer.schedule(runThis, 100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

will always call Sound.play(), but when I try

```
timer.schedule(runThis, 100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
Sound.play();
```

The method will only sometimes be called. I have these methods in a KeyListener keyPress method, and sometimes, when I press a key quickly and repeatedly, the `Sound.play()` method will not be called every time.

Why does the method only get called sometimes and not other times? Also, I notice that usually, when I repeat a key as soon as the previous 100 ms are over, the sound will not play.

**EDIT:** I also tried separating the contents of the `KeyPressed` method into their own method. In other words, I did this:

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    pressed();
}

public void pressed() {
    timer.schedule(runThis, 100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    Sound.play();
}
```

I also noticed that when using a separate method, even if `Sound.play()` was placed before the `timer.schedule()` method, the sound skipped every now and then. What could account for this?

Comment: it is hard to say anything with only 2 lines of code. what does `runThis` do? is `timer` an instance of `Timer` class? if yes, `Timer` has its own thread, there shouldn't be any issues

Comment: timer is a ScheduledExecutorService. runThis is a Runnable object that simply performs 1 line of code (change appearance of a JButton).

Comment: Have you tried using the 'keyTyped' callback instead ?

Comment: Yes, I noticed better results, but the sound still didn't play every now and then. P.S: I've edited the question and added more info.